# Iterate over two lists while i-1 condition is met in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two lists which I want to iterate through in a pairwise way to select pairs that meet my condition

```
list1 = [0, 6, 22, 29]
list2 = [3, 38, 48]
```

I iterate through them using `zip`:

```
for i, j in list(zip(list1, list2)):
  print(i, j)
```

This returns

```
0  3
6  38
22 48
```

This works fine but I want to build in the following condition:
The pair should only be returned if the first value (`i`) of a pair is larger than the last value (`j`) of the previous pair.

In this case, the first two pairs are correct, but the third is not since `22` is contained in `6:48`.

How can I build this logic into my loop?

Comment: By "previous pair", do you mean the previous pair in the unfiltered zip result, or the previous pair that has not been excluded from the output?

Comment: I mean the previous pair of the unfiltered zip result (which then can only be done from the second pair onwards). The xth pair is evaluated against the second value of the x-1th pair.

Comment: Are the integers guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: Yes, they are always positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to cast your `zip()` to a `list()`, as you are just iterating trough it.

Then, you can add a third list to the `zip()` which can be used to do the comparison. You can slice `list1` and `list2` because there is no "last `j` value of the previous pair" to compare with.

The third argument, `list2` will be used to check the condition. During the iteration, its element `k` is "one index late", so it is equal to the last `j` encountered.

```
for i, j, k in zip(list1[1:], list2[1:], list2):
    if i > k:
        print(i, j)
```

If you need to include the first pair, you can use this nice trick found by [@schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl):

```
for i, j, k in zip(list1, list2, [-1] + list2):
    if i > k:
        print(i, j)
```

Comment: Doesn't this miss the first pair?

Comment: This is very close to what I want to achieve. Yet, it does exclude the first pair of `0` and `3`

Comment: @ben_aaron It excludes it because there is no last `j` value to compare with. Do you want it to be included anyway?

Comment: insert this line instead and it will work: `for i, j, k in zip(list1, list2, [-1]+list2):`

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks!